# Prove that it is impossible to bound the integral of a product by the product of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

How to prove that there is no $c  \ge 0$ such that
$$
\Big|  \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx  \Big|  \le c  \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)| dx   \cdot   \int_{0}^{1} |g(x)| dx
$$
where $f,g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

Comment: Your formulation is wrong. You want a counter-example to the assertion: *There does not exist a constant $c>0$ such that for every continuous $f,g$ the inequality holds*

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x)=x^n=g(x)$. Then there is no $c$ so that
$$ \frac{1}{2n+1} \leqslant \frac{c}{(n+1)^2} $$
for every positive $n$.

Comment: I think the question is asking for every $f,g$, not just one particular example.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, you'd have thought I could integrate monomials by now... thanks.

Comment: @user2770287 To show a proposition is false, it suffices to find one example for which it isn't true. Were we trying to prove it was true, we would need to prove it in general.

Comment: Oh, I miss understood. I thought the result OP posted is true.